# sending an array in python using sockets

Tags: python, sockets

This is my python function:

```
  def handle(self):
        """
        The function handles the request
        :return: The function handles logging in.
        """

        str_db = open('db.json', 'r').read()
        json_db = json.loads(str_db)

        events_list = json_db['users'][self.username]['events']

        bytes_events_list = json.dumps(events_list).encode()

        self.sender_socket.send(bytes_events_list)
```

My question is - Can I send using sockets an array? 'events_list' contains a list of dictionaries. I'm turning it into bytes and then send it. Is it possible? because it doesn't work. If it's not possible. What are my other options?
Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you should be able to do this. `json.dumps()` will turn this into a JSON array of objects. The receiver should be able to use `json.loads()` to convert it back to a list of dictionaries.

Comment: "doesn't work" is not a good description of the problem. Do you get an error message? What is the receiver receiving if it's not the list of dictionaries?

Comment: The receiver uses json.loads()
it still doesn't work

Comment: You still say "doesn't work" without explaining what it's doing wrong. Please post a [mre]

Comment: Two "doesn't works" equal one close vote.